# I am looking for a Process to Create Daily Indices . That can Generate Logs report On daily basis

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, kibana-4

I am Using Kibana 6.4.3 and I want to Retain few month Logs but Untill I setup daily indices. Need a process to setup auto generation of Daily Indices.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be so kind and elaborate a little further. What exactly do you have (indices, elk-components)? How is your data flow? What are you expecting?

Comment: I have ELK 6.4.3 Installed on logstash server and and Using Kiabana we Monitor all the Logs. But We can check logs only for 14 days prior that means only two weeks logs are saved not rest. I want to create a process which can create Daily Indices and I can have the Logs saved.and the Indices need to be generated auto on daily bases and at particular time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [Rollover Index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-rollover-index.html#_defining_the_new_index).

I'd suggest you to refer to the link to see how it can be done. Basically you can simply execute the below queries to implement and test this `Rollover Index` feature

### Step 1: Create Initial Index

```
PUT /logs-000001
{
  "aliases": {
    "logs_write": {}
  }
}
```

### Step 2: Execute Rollover API

```
POST /logs_write/_rollover
{
  "conditions" : {
    "max_age": "1d",
    "max_docs": 1000,
    "max_size": "5gb"
  },
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_shards": 2
  }
}
```

What would happen is elasticsearch would go ahead and create index `logs-000002` after a day and so on and on.

> The API accepts a single alias name and a list of conditions. The
>   alias must point to a single index only. If the index satisfies the
>   specified conditions then a new index is created and the alias is
>   switched to point to the new index.

You can actually test the roll over using `dry_run` as shown in below query.

### Dry-Run Query

```
POST /logs_write/_rollover?dry_run
{
  "conditions" : {
    "max_age": "1d",
    "max_docs": 1000,
    "max_size": "5gb"
  }
}
```

When you run this test query, notice the response in the below format. It would show what would happen if the rollover happens after a day. Note that when you execute `dry run`, it doesn't create `logs-000002`.

### Dry Run Response

```
{
  "acknowledged": false,
  "shards_acknowledged": false,
  "old_index": "logs-000001",
  "new_index": "logs-000002",
  "rolled_over": false,
  "dry_run": true,
  "conditions": {
    "[max_age: 1d]": false,
    "[max_docs: 1000]": false,
    "[max_size: 5gb]": false
  }
}
```

### Important Note:

Rollover doesn't happen automatically. It has to be done manually using crontab or such scheduling tools and keep checking the conditions to execute rollover API programmatically.

Refer to this [LINK](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-is-rollover-not-automatic-and-field-based/114807) for more info on this

Hope it helps!

Comment: We need to execute the following in the KIbana GUI we have an option called DEVTOOL. So this should be executed there.

Comment: Yup yup. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: What if The indices are created and at a particular time interval everyday.

Comment: If I do not also run dry run I get the status False.

Comment: The index was created for logs-000001 with no Data in it. I think it's working. But in same way if I want to auto save the indexes which is daily generated. What would we the step for that.

Comment: Once index gets created, it wouldn't get deleted. So you'll have `logs-00001` as is, plus you'll have `logs-00002` the new index that'd be in use for accepting new data.

Comment: @Mohammed I've got what your concern is, you have to run periodically a cronjob or any client code to see if the condition as specified has been met. Auto Rollover doesn't happen. You need to execute the rollover APIs I've mentioned above explicitly.  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-is-rollover-not-automatic-and-field-based/114807

Comment: You can basically schedule and make use of curator API which I haven't explored https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/index.html